# Tree Grid Rally Portfolio Manager to Total Task Actuals on Story, Feature, Iniative and Theme Level

Tags: time, task, rally, agile

I was using the Rally Tree Grid app found here: 
https://github.com/Echo3ToEcho7/RallyTreeGrid

I was able to add the task time spent and task actuals column for my task, but i have been unable to get the sum of theses items to roll up to the user story, feature, initiative or theme level in this view.  Would anyone be able to assist thanks?

Comment: There is TaskActualTotal on a user story (HierarchicalRequirement) object in WS API. Did you add this to your columns? Is Actuals visible in your workspace?

Comment: Yes, I added the the TaskActualTotal and it did populate on the tasks, butthe sum of those tasks actuals did not populate for the parent user story > feature > initiative > theme

Answer (score 0):

Per [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) object model TaskEstimateTotal, TaskRemainingTotal, TaskActualTotal exist on UserStories (HierarchicalRequirement). Those fileds do not exist on Tasks. Tasks have Estimate and Actuals attributes. I assume when you say "TaskActualTotal populate on the tasks" you mean Estimate or Actuals populates on the tasks.

There is no attribute on PortfolioItem object in WS API object model where tasks esimates rollup to PI, or where TaskEstimateTotal, TaskRemainingTotal, TaskActualTotal of the associated user stories  rollup to PI.

It is possible keep a count of TaskActualTotal values on stories and sum them up in your javascript code, but there is no shortcut, and that works with [Rally.data.custom.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.custom.Store).

PI object has a LeafStoryPlanEstimateTotal attribute which is a  sum of the plan estimates of all leaf user stories (stories without children) associated with this Portfolio Item.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get similar data (cost of porfolio items in terms of task estimates and timespent from timesheet), but it seems that there is no easy way.
even though i can get custom reports for tasks, timespent from timespeet, user stories etc, There isn't a custom report capability to get portfolio information.

I've created and Idea / Feature request for something that does this or atleast makes it possible, Feel free to vote it up to get visibility on it to the Rally team
https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D3120